# How to pull the top checked in places using FQL?

Tags: facebook-fql, facebook-opengraph

Is there anyway to pull up the top 10 places that are checked into using FQL?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. You can only query FQL by indexed fields - like by user id and page id. Not query by other properties.